# PHPUnit 6.1.x throws array_merge() error when my test class uses its own constructor method

Tags: php, constructor, phpunit, extends

I get this error:

```
1) XTest::testX
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

On this test case:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class XTest extends TestCase
{

    function __construct()
    {}

    function testX()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

If I remove `__construct` method, my tests pass.  What is going on with PHPUnit's handling of my class constructor methods?  It worked fine in PHPUnit version 4.8, but now I am using PHPUnit version 6.1.3

Comment: what if you call `parent::__construct();` ? The signature can be found here https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.1.3/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L328

Comment: interestingly, it will not throw error if I use `parent::__construct();`

Comment: You are better off using the `setUp()` methods for initialization. Further more you can get a stacktrace when your run phpunit with the `-v` verbose flag.

Comment: How would you use `setUp()` for initialization?  Sometimes I have classes that use `__construct()` method legitimately.  How would you use `setUp` on them?...

Comment: `setUp` is automatically called by phpunit after your constructor is called.
You can find more information about other method here : https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html

Comment: You can't override a method that requires an argument with one that doesn't (well theoretically you could, but you never should)

Comment: thanks, thus perhaps I can rename my `__constructor` to say `setUp` for any initialization tasks, although in my case I need to initialize it once per class, while `setUp` does it once per test case

Comment: You can also use `setUpBeforeClass` which is called really once.  `setUp` is called for every specified test in your class.

Comment: also just to note, using `-v` option did not uncover any more info in my case, it gave the same error message, and i.e. did not give me the offending line where it crashed.  I had to sleuth this one out.  I am curious though that if I use `parent::__construct()`, still without any parameters, it did work fine

Comment: The verbose flag doesn't work you're right

Comment: It happens because the constructor of the TestCase sets `$this->data = []`

Comment: There is no reason to implement `__construct()` in a `TestCase`. Use `setUp()` for initialization. It is invoked before each test.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

PHPUnit uses the constructor for initialization of the base `TestCase`

You can see the constructor method here: 
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/6.1.3/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L328

```
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
```

You shouldn't use the constructor, because it's used by phpunit and any change to the signature etc can break things.

You can use the special `setUp` and `setUpBeforeClass` methods which phpunit will call for you.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class XTest extends TestCase
{
    function static setUpBeforeClass()
    { 
       // Called once just like normal constructor
       // You can create database connections here etc
    }

    function setUp()
    {
      //Initialize the test case
      //Called for every defined test
    }

    function testX()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    // Clean up the test case, called for every defined test
    public function tearDown() { }

    // Clean up the whole test class
    public static function tearDownAfterClass() { }
}
```

The docs: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html

Note that the `setUp` gets called for every specified test in the class.

For a single initialization you can use `setUpBeforeClass`.

And another tip: run your phpunit with the `-v` flag to display stack traces ;)

Comment: it looks like `setUpBeforeClass` needs to be static to work properly, while `setUp` does not need to be

Comment: No, using the constructor is not a solution. Use `setUp()`.

Comment: Hey sebastian could you explain that a bit? I know it's bad practice but not sure the reasons behind it.

Comment: The constructor "belongs" to PHPUnit. `setUp()` is the extension point for users.

Comment: So by overwriting the `__constructor` you should follow the exact same constructor signature defined by phpunit. Therefor it's dis encouraged because users can easily break things

Comment: @SebastianBergmann I find it logical. However since it did work in PHPUnit 4.8, it would be very nice to see a bit more descriptive error message than ``array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array``. Maybe a hint like ``setUp() should be used instead of __construct()``.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann Using setUp or setUpBeforeClass seems a not complete solution because they are static classes. No way to init data like $this->myvarforothermethod = ....   Adding  parent::__construct(); in custom constructor solve the trouble for me and make my tests compatible with phpunit v6.1 and lower.

Answer (score 20):

As Sander Visser's answer correctly pointed, the parent constructor might have additional parameters, etc, and generally you'd want to use `setUpBeforeClass` or `setUp`, but, if you know what you're doing, you can call `parent::__construct();` in the constructor of your Test class:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    // Your construct here
}
```

#### Edit 2019

In Codeception, this can also be caused by an invalid YML indentation on your suite file.

Comment: better solution

Comment: +1: useful for when you want to set non-static variables once for the test class - even though that may not be good practice. Tests may not be atomic if the state of those non-static variables changes from test to test.

Comment: I think it would be great and easiest to start for all.